# When inserting an element using insertAdjacentHTML, the element is no longer picked up by queryselector

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new at this. Thank you for your help! I have a function that is called when you press one of four buttons. Button ONE makes FIELD ONE disappear. The other three buttons are supposed to bring that field back...but then button ONE should make it disappear. The best way I've figured out how to do this is below.

I think the issue is that when I re-insert the field using insertAdjacentHTML, queryselector no longer detects it...maybe because of something with the DOM loading? Thanks in advance.

```
const function = function (e) {
  
  if (this.id === "BUTTON ONE") 
     {FIELDONE.forEach((item) => item.remove());}
 
  else if (
    this.id !== "BUTTON ONE" &&
    this.querySelector("[class]") == undefined
  ) {document.getElementById("[ID]").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "[html text]");} ;
};
```

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const Type = document.querySelectorAll(".main-field");


const typeOfLit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.id === "type2") Type.forEach((item) => item.remove()); 
  else if (
    this.id !== "type2" &&
    this.querySelector(".main-field") == undefined
  ) {

    document
      .getElementById("another-field")
      .insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterend",
        "<label class='main-field'>Main</label><input class='main-field' type='text'  />"
      );
  } else return;
};



btns.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click", typeOfLit));
```

```html
<form class="modal__form">
  <button class="btn" id="type1">Book</button>
  <button class="btn" id="type2">Article</button>
  <button class="btn" id="type3">Website</button>
  <button class="btn" id="type4">Other</button><br>
  <label>Author</label><input type="text" id="another-field" />
  <label class="magazine-field">Magazine</label><input class="main-field" type="text" />

</form>
```

Comment: Instead of adding and removing elements dynamically, it's often better to create them all in the original HTML, and use CSS to hide and show them.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Will make this minimal reproducible. Thank you! The problem with hiding is that there was a white space where the fields were and the rest of the elements did not shift up. Is there a way to fix that through hidding/revealing?

Comment: Don't put whitespace between the HTML tags.

Comment: @Barmar I think I got the snipped down. The whitespace was there because a the html field that was there was removed. The whitespace didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

`Type` contains the `.main-field` elements that were in the DOM when the page was first loaded. It's not a "live" NodeList, so adding/removing element with the class doesn't update it automatically. You need to reassign the variable whenever you add or remove these elements.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let Type = document.querySelectorAll(".main-field");

const typeOfLit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.id === "type2") Type.forEach((item) => item.remove());
  else if (
    this.id !== "type2" &&
    this.querySelector(".main-field") == undefined
  ) {
    document
      .getElementById("another-field")
      .insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterend",
        "<label class='main-field'>Main</label><input class='main-field' type='text'  />"
      );
  }
  Type = document.querySelectorAll(".main-field");
};


btns.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click", typeOfLit));
```

```html
<form class="modal__form">
  <button class="btn" id="type1">Book</button>
  <button class="btn" id="type2">Article</button>
  <button class="btn" id="type3">Website</button>
  <button class="btn" id="type4">Other</button><br>
  <label>Author</label><input type="text" id="another-field" />
  <label class="magazine-field">Magazine</label><input class="main-field" type="text" />

</form>
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the test `this.querySelector(".main-field") == undefined`. `this` is one of the buttons, and there are no `.main-field` elements in any of the buttons. So that test will always be true. Also, `querySelector()` returns `null` when it doesn't find a matching element; although the comparison will succeed because of type juggling, it would be better to write `== null` (or more simply `!this.querySelector(".main-field")`).

Comment: Barmar! Thank you!! That worked both as to saving it as a variable and also your catch on the always-null issue. Really appreciate your time. I am researching more about this to educate myself--appreciate it!